# Python function arguments from MySql database?

Tags: python, mysql

I have seen data retrieval from MySQL that can be output in the python interpreter, but I'm wondering if it is possible to retrieve some data from a MySQL db that is then used as parameters for a Python function.

Let's pretend I have some function that is:

```
def doggy(name, goodOrBad, colour, breed):    
    print (name + " is a " + goodOrBad + " boy, who is a " + colour + " " + breed + ".")
```

Given the parameters this outputs something like:

```
"Max is a good boy who is a chocolate lab."
```

Is it possible to pull data from MySQL tables to use as the parameters for this function? Or should I simply try to pull the pieces of data and then save them in to variables in a separate function and then call "doggy" from the new function with the variables as parameters?

Something like:

```
def doggyParams():
    a = "Max"
    b = "good"
    c = "chocolate"
    d = "Lab"


   doggy(a, b, c, d)

doggyParams()
```

I'm not sure if this is possible -- to retrieve the data and then store them as variables? Or if it is a bad idea?

Thanks all, first post here, and I don't *think* this is a duplicate or repost.

Cheers,
LC-Data

Comment: "Is it possible to pull data from MySQL tables to use as the parameters for this function? " Well yes of course why ??? What would be the use for a database if you couldn't retrieve data from it and use them in your code actually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to pull data from MySQL tables to use as the parameters
>   for this function?

It is not a problem as well.

You can pull data from MySQL, store it and use it in any way:

```
def doggyParams():
   query = "select a, b, c, d from params where id = 1"
   cursor.execute(query)
   a, b, c, d = cursor.fetchone()
   doggy(a, b, c, d)

doggyParams()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be done like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","test123","TESTDB" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# sql = Query which will return your required rows
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
   results = cursor.fetchall()
   for row in results:
      name = row[0]
      good_or_bad = row[1]
      color = row[2]
      breed = row[3]
      doggy(name, good_or_bad, color, breed)
except:
   print "Error: unable to fecth data"

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```